# What are the following permissions in octal: "-r----x--t"

Tags: permissions

A bug in our Ansible code changed the permissions of a file to `-r----x--t`. What are those permissions in octal? Is it `1410`?

Comment: So many people here in this Q&A using The One True Base without the Holy Leading `0`!  (-:

Comment: octal 01411 = decimal 777. Which also isn't affected by the default umask (`(777 & ~022) == 01411`). For octal 01410 the symbolic permissions would've been `-r----x--T` (with an uppercase `T` = sticky bit but no search/execute permissions for others).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is: `01411`.

This means that the user that owns the file as `read` permission; the group (which excludes the owner) has `execution` permission and the last `t` letter represents the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit). It is represented by the lowercase letter t in the final character-place, replacing what would otherwise be x.

Note: Since is a lowercase `t` `Others` must have e`x`ecution permission for the stick bit to work.

Here is a link to an online [Unix Permissions Calculator](http://permissions-calculator.org/).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know the file permissions for a file, you can use the `stat` command.  For example:

```
$ stat myFile
  File: myFile
  Size: 4823            Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 28h/40d Inode: 12345602    Links: 1
Access: (1411/-r----x--t)  Uid: ( 1000/ username)   Gid: ( 1000/ groupname)
Access: 2020-01-08 12:14:17.348071278 -0500
Modify: 2020-01-08 12:14:17.348071278 -0500
Change: 2020-01-08 12:22:26.156231191 -0500
 Birth: -
```

Specifically notice the `Access` field, which includes the numeric and symbol representation of the permissions on the file.